# loadwallet takes too much and times out

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

Hardware is too old and wallet was too much unsynchronized.

Loading the wallet took so much time, it timed out (pending missing console output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bitcoind side, that's perfectly normal and safe operation.

Timeout happens only client side.

For a more elegant client (bitcoin-cli) operation, can use:
`-rpcclienttimeout=0`.

> Timeout in seconds during HTTP requests, or 0 for no timeout (default: 900)